# How does a Spring Boot Application create beans without @Configuration class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am pretty new to Spring Boot Application. I wanted to understand how does a spring Boot Application create beans without @Configuration class . I had a look at a sample project where there was neither @Bean definitions nor a component scan yet @Autowired provided the dependency to the class. Please have a look at the snippet below:

```
@RestController
public class RestController{

**@Autowired
public CertificationService certificationService;**
.
.
.
.
}

//Interface

public interface CertificationService{

public List<Certification> findAll();

}

//Implementation Class
@Transactional
@Service

public class CertificationServiceImpl{

public List<Certification> findAll(){
.
.
}

}
```

My limited knowledge of springs tells me that when there is a @Service annotation over a class, there has to be a @ComponentScan somewhere to create the bean. But without a component scan, how does the CertificationServiceImpl bean gets created and thereby how does the autowiring of CertificationService in RestController works here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [said](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html) in documentation:

> ... The `@SpringBootApplication` annotation is equivalent to using
>   `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan`...

Let say you have Spring Boot app class something like:

```
package com.mypackage;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;    
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication    
public class SpringBootApplication {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootApplication.class, args);    
    }    
}
```

Then all packages below of package `com.mypackage` will be scanned by default for Spring components. By the way, you can specify packages to scan right in `@SpringBootApplication` annotation, without usage of `@ComponentScan`. More details [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html).